# No overload matches this call when trying to send StorageEvent - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently developing an application in Angular which saves the current state of the app in the local storage.

I saw that you can subscribe to a StorageEvent, so when running the app in 2 different tabs and modifying the data, the state is updated simultaneously in both tabs.

I've written the subscription as follows:

```
this.storageListenSub = fromEvent(window, 'storage').subscribe(
      (event: StorageEvent) => {
        if (event.key === 'notes') this.loadState();
      }
    );
```

The loadState function is described below:

```
 loadState() {
    try {
      const notesInStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes')!);
      // if (!notesInStorage) return;

      this.notes.length = 0; //clear the notes array while keeping referenece
      this.notes.push(...notesInStorage);

      this.notes = notesInStorage;
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('There was an error retrieving the notes from local storage');
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 3, '(observer?:
> Partial<Observer> | undefined): Subscription', gave the
> following error.
> Type '(event: StorageEvent) => void' has no properties in common with type 'Partial<Observer>'.   Overload 2 of 3, '(next:
> (value: Event) => void): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(event: StorageEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Event) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'event' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'StorageEvent': key, newValue, oldValue, storageArea, and 2 more.
> Overload 3 of 3, '(next?: ((value: Event) => void) | null | undefined,
> error?: ((error: any) => void) | null | undefined, complete?: (() =>
> void) | null | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(event: StorageEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Event) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'event' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'StorageEvent'.ts(2769)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try with  (event: any) => { } instead of StorageEvent

Answer (score 1):

You can add a type to `fromEvent`

```js
fromEvent<StorageEvent>(
  window, 'storage'
).subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Saved me a lot of time. Cheers